# "Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" when importing litepie-datepicker into VueJS project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, datepicker, vue-component

I imported [litepie-datepicker](https://litepie.com/) into my VueJS 2 project that already uses TailwindCSS,

but i get this error:

```
litepie-datepicker.esm.js?8527:119 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at eval (litepie-datepicker.esm.js?8527:119)
    at Module../node_modules/litepie-datepicker/dist/litepie-datepicker.esm.js (chunk-vendors.js:2216)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (main.js:13)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1379)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Object.1 (app.js:1584)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
```

I saw while searching that others also have the same issue, but not solution proposed. I have no clue where this is comming from. any guess ?

Here is my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import App from '@/App.vue';
import applyPrototypes from '@/helpers/applyPrototypes.js';
import LitepieDatepicker from 'litepie-datepicker';
import router from './router'
import './index.css'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
applyPrototypes(Vue);

// Vue.use(LitepieDatepicker);
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const app = new Vue({
  router,

  render: function (hyperscript) {
    return hyperscript(App);
  }
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @hotcakedev nope, i didn't have much time to investigate and it wouldn't be worth it, i just gave up on that library and use this instead: https://innologica.github.io/vue2-daterange-picker